# Xml exchange between Server side and Client Side using Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using the Spring MVC framework edition 3.0.2 for the client side. The server side is already developed(with django) and upload on a server.Also, server side implemements REST web service. On the server there is something like this:

```
 <atom:link rel="data" type="application/xml" href="http://www.../ckp/data/"/>
```

That i want to do is to take this data(xml file) from the http://www.../ckp/data/ and print it on a view with the use of the spring framework. Actually i'm very new and i don't know how to treat this. What should i change on the client side and where? i mean should i change something on the dispatcher-servlet-Config.xml or in the web.xml or somewhere else?And in the controller? what should i write or call?
Is there an annotation which can be used to take an xml document from a specific url?

The second part of my question is how i can send and xml file to the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look like this [sample](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82146-Spring-RESTful-Client-Server-tutorial). It explain how to do an REST web service with Spring 3